# Yii ограничивает меня? Философия framework

Tags: yii, framework, фреймворк

У меня философский вопрос по поводу использования framework Yii.

Через `createCommand()->QueryAll()` я получаю массив :

```
array(
0 => array('id'=>100,'subid'=>2,'anyfield'=>'anydata1'),
1 => array('id'=>101,'subid'=>2,'anyfield'=>'anydata2'),
2 => array('id'=>102,'subid'=>4,'anyfield'=>'anydata3'),
3 => array('id'=>103,'subid'=>4,'anyfield'=>'anydata4'),
4 => array('id'=>104,'subid'=>8,'anyfield'=>'anydata5'),
)
```

Но мне нужно получить массив, который был бы сгруппирован по subid примерно так:

```
array(
2 => array(
           array('id'=>100,'anyfield'=>'anydata1'),
           array('id'=>101,'anyfield'=>'anydata2')
          ),
4 => array(
           array('id'=>102,'anyfield'=>'anydata3'),
           array('id'=>103,'anyfield'=>'anydata4')
          ),
8 => array(
           array('id'=>104,'anyfield'=>'anydata5')
          ),
)
```

На сколько я понял, средствами framework такое не решить.

Вопрос: что мне делать?

1 вариант: написать на mysql_query и mysql_fetch_assoc. (что не в духе framework)

2 вариант: переформатировать массив.(пострадает производительность)

Дело не конкретно в данном примере, а в том, что такие проблемы будут всплывать время от времени. Но решать похожими вариантами не очень бы хотелось

Эти 2 решения - костыли. **Хотелось бы услышать от вас совета в общем**.

Comment: переформировать массив как предложил @lampa и да производительность будет страдать, поэтому я бы несколько раз подумал, а стоит ли оно того или в принципе задачу поставить можно по другому.

Answer (score 4):

```
array_walk($arr, function ($item, $key, $arr) {
    $result[$item['subid']][] = $item;
}, &$result);
```

А запрос, выполненный не через фреймфорк может вылиться в нечто непредсказуемое.

Comment: а к примеру, что может вылиться в непредсказуемое и как?

Comment: @Сержо допустим в Yii запрос выглядит так: 

    $db->query->select("rows")->from("table")->...

Что происходит внутри - неизвестно. Возможно в таком запросе куча всевозможных проверок, счетчиков и т.п. Возможно, что rows и table это изменяемые столбцы и таблицы. Возможно всё, что угодно. 

Скрипт же, который выше, не так сильно влияет на производительность, экономия на спичках.

Answer (score 0):

SQL, в обычном случае, выдает плоскую таблицу (массив), возможно использовать процедуры или возможности выдачи xml json, но это совсем другая история и зависит от конкретного SQL сервера (MySql PostreSql SQL Server...), не через QueryAll(). Возможно не так используете возможности SQL или плохо сформулирована задача. В простейшем случае на каждую группу для вашего желания нужно формировать отдельный запрос, выбирать данные по WHERE, если нужны групповые агрегатные вычисления, используйте Group by. Или получите таблицу (массив) сортированный по нужному набору полей и используйте дополнительную обработку для преобразования в нужную вам структуру данных, сортировка поможет легче преобразовать данные...